# Renaming type for FSharp.Data JsonProvider

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have a JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "names": [
        {
            "value": "Name",
            "language": "en"
        }
    ],
    "descriptions": [
        {
            "value": "Sample description",
            "language" "en"
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

When using `JsonProvider` from the `FSharp.Data` library, it maps both fields as the same type `MyJsonProvider.Name`. This is a little confusing when working with the code. Is there any way how to rename the type to `MyJsonProvider.NameOrDescription`? I have read that this is possible for the [CsvProvider](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html), but typing

```
JsonProvider<"./Resources/sample.json", Schema="Name->NameOrDescription">
```

results in an error.

Also, is it possible to define that the `Description` field is actually an `Option<MyJsonProvider.NameOrDescription>`? Or do I just have to define the JSON twice, once with all possible values and the second time just with mandatory values?

```
[
    {
        ...
        "names": [
            {
                "value": "Name",
                "language": "en"
            }
        ],
        "descriptions": [
            {
                "value": "Sample description",
                "language" "en"
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "names": [
            {
                "value": "Name",
                "language": "en"
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, I do not think there is a way of specifying such renaming. It would be quite reasonable option, but the JSON provider could also be more clever when generating names here (it knows that the type can represent `Name` or `Description`, so it could generate a name with `Or` based on those).

As a hack, you could add an unusued field with the right name:

```
type A = JsonProvider<"""{
    "do not use": { "value_with_langauge": {"value":"A", "language":"A"} },
    "names": [ {"value":"A", "language":"A"} ],
    "descriptions": [ {"value":"A", "language":"A"} ]
  }""">
```

To answer your second question - your `names` and `descriptions` fields are already arrays, i.e. `ValueWithLanguge[]`. For this, you do not need an optional value. If they are not present, the provider will simply give you an empty array.